# How to render a stitched image as a single resource in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, image, render

So I've created a component that contains the basic components to generating a border frame of any size. I have images for the corners and a small section of each side. The idea is that the corners are placed, then the distance between each corner is filled in by X number of side images where X is calculated based on the width/height of the frame. So this is the idea:

corner images (NOTE: each of these images is unique and have their own shading/lighting, so I can't replace the 4 corners or 4 sides with a single image):

```
top_left: /
top_right: \
bottom_right: /
bottom_ left: \
right_side: |
left_ side: |
top_side: -
bottom_side: -
```

to generate for example:

```
/---------\
|         |
| content |
|         |
\---------/
```

My component basically works like this:

```
<div main>
    <img top-right-corner/>
    {return a list of <img side> tags based on side height}
    <img top-left-corner/>
    {return a list of <img side> tags based on side height}
    <img bottom-right-corner/>
    {return a list of <img side> tags based on side width}
    <img bottom-left-corner/>
    {return a list of <img side> tags based on side width}
</div>
```

The problem is that when I have a list of elements that all use this frame, it not only takes a while to load, but if the list is scrollable, the scrolling is quite framey.

I'm thinking the best way would be to generate the frame to be only a single  instead of a whole lot of nested and styled images to fit right. Is there a way I can optimize this to not be slow loading/scrolling?

Comment: You could use [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) or you could use [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds) on your `div` to set it up.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I can see how border-image might work but the problem is that each side and each corner is different due to 3D lighting, so I need to have 8 different images to properly generate the 4 corners and 4 sides.